# Странное поведение при смене opacity

Tags: html, css, transform

Есть код, 2 прозрачных блока, один из которых условно наезжает по диагонали на другой

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 660px;
  perspective: 400px;
}

section div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 220px;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  opacity: .7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: orange;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.transform {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: .7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: notransform 5s infinite;
}

.translate3d {
  transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 20px);
}

@keyframes notransform {
  50% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="transform translate3d"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

При удалении `opacity: .7` у класса `.cont` прозрачность меняется, 
НО
также меняется угол наезда одного блока на другой (приложил скрин).

В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не скажу в чем именно проблема, надо ковыряться... Но исправить можно так...  Задай побольше `perspective: 1000px;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 660px;
  /* perspective: 400px; */
}

section div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 220px;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  /* opacity: .7; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: orange;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.transform {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: .7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: notransform 5s infinite;
}

.translate3d {
  transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 20px);
}

@keyframes notransform {
  50% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="transform translate3d"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

@Air Правильно заметил что дело в `perspective`. Если не используется то можно убрать полностью, или же подобрать значение между 1000px-1500px, чтобы анимация выглядела как нужно.